# Should we reject an edit that fundamentally changes an off topic question on translating books?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A user heavily edited someone else's closed question [I want a book to be translated into my native language?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/130945/i-want-a-book-to-be-translated-into-my-native-language) to change the question from focusing on a popular fiction book (which seems clearly off topic) to a hypothetical academic text book. The edited question seems to be on topic to me and likely to receive the votes needed to be reopened. It also seems to stray vary far from the OP’s question.

I personally think we should reject the edit and keep the original question closed. If the OP wishes to edit the question, or if someone else wishes to ask the new question, they can do that.

Comment: Quick question: An upvote here means "we should reject the edit", right?

Comment: @user109129 The upvote is mine and just means "thanks for asking this question".

Comment: @user109129 nominally up/down votes on meta being yes/no only apply to feature requests and even then it is confusing. But yes, I wrote the title and question in a way that upvotes mean reject the edit.

Answer (score 12):

I thought it was strange to edit a question that was clearly off-topic into something very different simply for the sake of "saving" it. It also introduces weird things, like the OP of the off-topic question gaining or losing reputation based on up/downvotes to a question they clearly didn't ask. I felt it would make more sense for the altered question to be asked as a new post.

I'm fine with any decision on the matter (I certainly wouldn't repeatedly revert).

Answer (score 2):

Edits to questions by people who are not the author should never change the basic intent of the question. It's really, really rude to the author. If such an edit is proposed, it should be rejected.

I've been on the receiving end of such edits on another site, where my question has been changed into something different to what I asked, and IMHO into something asinine. I've had to contact moderators to get my name taken off it.

Comment: You should have reverted the edit, and flagged if an edit war statred.

Comment: @DavidRicherby by the time I saw it, the new question had a couple of answers...

Comment: Ah, OK. That sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me note that there have been other questions here that have been edited to change (IMO) the intent as it seemed to be expressed by the OP. I think that such things need to be handled consistently. It was that memory, actually, that seemed to give me "permission" to make the change.

I won't speak, however, in favor of allowing such changes and generally don't favor them. And I've hesitated as well to roll back those changes.

Comment: I asked (and self-answered) a [follow-up question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4493/7734) on how to draw the line here.

Answer (score -1):

I'll make no objection. I thought my edit made for an interesting on-topic question and also commented apologies in advance to the OP. Anyone with sufficient rep to edit could change it back as was done. Fine. I have no issue with it.

I deleted my answer, as it applied more to the edited question than the original, which I agree was off topic. Again, no worries.

Comment: Glad to hear you have an open mind, not that I was worried. If we reject the edit, there is no reason not to ask your version as a new question.